# Is there a tool to automatically extract common subroutines from files?

Tags: perl, svn, ide, refactoring

I have two 1000+ line programs in Perl, each with about 20 subroutines in the main file. One was forked from the other some time ago and I want to factor out the common parts (before porting features backward.) Is there a diff tool that will treat the subroutines (and preceding comments) as units, and extract the common units into a new file? (if one line of a subroutine is different, the unit doesn’t match.)

My SCM is currently Subversion if that helps.  A Perl script that processes the code would be cool.

Comment: I don't know of tool doing what you want directly, but you can make such extractor with [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PPI) module.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1464098/469210 for a question about a semantically aware diff for C++.

Comment: Apropos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575224/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use the [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-1.215/lib/PPI.pm) module; to my knowledge there's no tool for refactoring as the one you mentioned.

Comment: PPI worked for me, mostly. Something went wrong with HERE documents. But now I have a tool that automatically makes the first cut.

Answer (score 1):

If you had 500,000 lines of code it might be useful to have or write such a tool.  For 1000 lines, this shouldn't be too hard with a simple visual diff tool, like BeyondCompare ($) or WinMerge (free).

Comment: it's the principle of the thing.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare two different versions of the files?

I use [VIM](http://www.vim.org) which comes with a built in diff program *vimdiff* and a fully gui one called *gvimdiff*. It'll *fold* common lines and just show you the lines that differ and where.

With *gvim*, you can open up three splits in one window (the two versions and a blank) and then copy over the various lines you want. If you're using Subversion, you can use the built in merge tool (if you're talking about different versions of the same file). The Subversion merge is pretty good and will probably help you with the merge issues.

Comment: No, re-read the question. There are plenty of diff tools that only operate on a line level.